# C++: recompiling old code using owl

Tags: c++, c++builder, owlnext

I'm trying to compile an old program with the new Borland C++-Builder (Embarcadero Studio XE2).

I thought it would be easy, but I get a lot of errors. e.g. using something like `somefunction(TPoint(0,0))` won't work when it's expecting a reference, so I had to write `TPoint t=TPoint(0,0);somefunction(t)`... also some errors like math.log could work with double of float but got uint, so it can't decide...

But the main Problem seems to regard OWL. I have a codeline there that says something about mismatching function parameter types:

> DEFINE_RESPONSE_TABLE1(TTSCalibDialog, TDialog)
>     EV_LVN_ENDLABELEDIT(IDC_CALIBMASSES,  MassCol_EndLableEditResp),
>     EV_COMMAND(IDC_CALIBRATEBUT,        CalibrateResp),
>     EV_COMMAND(IDC_CALIBSAVEBUT,        CalibSaveResp),
>     EV_COMMAND(IDC_CALIBLOADBUT,        CalibLoadResp),
>     EV_COMMAND(IDC_CALIBRESTORE,        CalibRestoreResp),
>     EV_COMMAND(IDC_CALIBSETNUMMASSES, CalibSetNumMassesResp),
>     EV_WM_DESTROY, //   Ev_WM_Destroy END_RESPONSE_TABLE;

The line

`EV_LVN_ENDLABELEDIT(IDC_CALIBMASSES, MassCol_EndLableEditResp)`

gives the error

> [BCC32 Fehler] AcMode_TS_Dial.CPP(13): E2285 Keine Übereinstimmung für
>   'b_LV_DISPINFO_NOTIFY_Sig(void
>   (TTSCalibDialog::*)(TLvDispInfoNotify &))' gefunden
>   while the second argument is declared
>   void   MassCol_EndLableEditResp(TLwDispInfoNotify& nmHdr)
>   {MassCol->EndLableEditResp(nmHdr);};

The first argument seems also legit to use here...

Later there is a line used

> EV_LVN_ENDLABELEDIT(IDC_SIMWEIGHTCOL,AddCol0_EndLableEditResp),

with the same error, so I think there might be an include or namespace missing...

Does anyone know this function or what could cause the error?

Comment: Just curious - did you resolve this issue? I saw from your other post that you are using OWLNext

Comment: @Jogy Ah, I forgot to answer this question. I got help in the owlNext-forum that told me I was using a wrog return type. See the answer below for that in detail^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time I asked in the OWLNext-Forum, too, recieving the right answer there:

http://sourceforge.net/p/owlnext/discussion/97175/thread/a0cc4131/

```
void TTSCalibDialog::MassCol_EndLableEditResp(TLwDispInfoNotify& nmHdr) 
{MassCol->EndLableEditResp(nmHdr);}
```

This function returns void, however, bool is required. Changing the type and returning true inside solved this issue.

There were a few other issues as well, but now the program is happily compiling on the XE2-Studio.